# Weird Glitch in program with arrow keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, arrow-keys

So my program here takes wasd or arrow keys from user otherwise it is supposed to give an error:

```
import termios
import tty, sys
def getVal():
    old = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdin)
    tty.setcbreak(sys.stdin.fileno())
    try:
        key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
        while key not in [119, 97, 115, 100, 65, 66, 67, 68]:
            print("Please enter w, a, s, or d OR arrow keys only.")
            key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))

        if key == 119 or key == 65:
            print('up')
        elif key == 97 or key == 68:
            print('left')
        elif key == 115 or key == 66:
            print('down')
        elif key == 100 or key == 67:
            print('right')
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdin, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
while True:
    getVal()
```

The wasd commands work fine but when I try to do any arrow keys(in this case the down one) this happens:

```
Please enter w, a, s, or d OR arrow keys only.
Please enter w, a, s, or d OR arrow keys only.
down
```

It is giving me 2 error messages and a down even though it should only give the down message. Why is this happening?

Comment: You can write `while key not in [119,97,115, ...]:` to make your code more readable.

Comment: Oh thanks wondering what i could do to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

When you press an arrow key (as opposed to a literal key), *three* values are generated: 27 ("escape"), 91, and the actual arrow key (say, 68). If the first value you read is 27, then you should read the next two and decipher only the last one. You should replace this line:

```
key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
```

with:

```
key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
if key == 27:
    sys.stdin.read(1) # Skip the next character, must be 91
    key = ord(sys.stdin.read(1))
```

Comment: Without making it so that if they actually press what ever key belongs to 27 or 91  it gives the error.

Comment: No I mean that there are 2 of those lines

Comment: Both lines are doing exactly the same thing, and they are doing it wrong. So, replace both.